# How to make Java rest api call return immediately not wait?

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/endpoint", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> endpoint(@RequestBody final ObjectNode data, final HttpServletRequest request) {
        somefunction();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }


public somefunction() {
 .....
 }
```

In Java spring controller, I have an endpoint. When this endpoint is called, I want it return directly, not wait `somefunction()` to finish. Any could teach me how to deal with this?

Comment: start `somefunction()` on other `thread`

Comment: RxJava is used for that

Answer (score 14):

If you are using Java 8, you can use the new `Executor` classes:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/endpoint", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> endpoint(@RequestBody final ObjectNode data, final HttpServletRequest request) {
    Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1).schedule(
        () -> somefunction(),
        10, TimeUnit.SECONDS
    );
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
}
```

This will:

1. Schedule `somefunction()` to run after a 10 second delay.
2. Return HTTP 202 Accepted (which is what you should return when your POST endpoint does not actually create anything on the spot).
3. Run `somefunction()` after 10 seconds have passed.

Answer (score 4):

change line

```
somefunction();
```

to be

```
new Thread()
{
    public void run() {
        somefunction();
    }
}.start();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `RxJava` which offers you promises. You will have `DefferedResult` which will be returned asynchronously, so it won't block other methods from being executed.

For example:

```
@RequestMapping("/getAMessageFutureAsync")
public DeferredResult<Message> getAMessageFutureAsync() {
    DeferredResult<Message> deffered = new DeferredResult<>(90000);
    CompletableFuture<Message> f = this.service1.getAMessageFuture();
    f.whenComplete((res, ex) -> {
        if (ex != null) {
            deffered.setErrorResult(ex);
        } else {
            deffered.setResult(res);
        }
    });
    return deffered;
}
```

[--Code source and tutorial](http://www.java-allandsundry.com/2015/03/using-rx-java-observable-in-spring-mvc.html)